# Django return HttpResponseRedirect to an url with a parameter

Tags: django, url, httpresponse, urlvariables

I have a situation in my project where i need to make a **redirection** of the user to an `url` containing a parameter, it is declared in the **urls.py** like:

```
url(r'^notamember/(?P<classname>\w+)/$', 
                           notamember,
                           name='notamember'),)
```

How can i put that parameter in the return `HttpResponseRedirect`? I tried like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/classroom/notamember/classname')
```

anyway, this is foolish, i know, i cannot consider the **classmane** as a parameter.
For clarity, my **view.py** is:

```
def leave_classroom(request,classname):
    theclass = Classroom.objects.get(classname = classname)
    u = Membership.objects.filter(classroom=theclass).get(member = request.user).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/classroom/notamember/theclass/')
```

How can i include the variable **theclass** in that `url`?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/classroom/notamember/%s/' % classname)
```

**EDIT:**

This is surely better (Daniel Roseman's answer):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('notamember', kwargs={'classname': classname})
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: hmmm... it doesn't seem to work - the classname still doesn't appear in the url :(

Comment: what does the `notamember` view do ?

Comment: gives the user access only to the resources available for non members. its signature is def notamember(request,classname):

Comment: From the urls.py you included I understand that you want that when the user goes to 127.0.0.1:8000/notamember/myclass/, the browser will redirect to 127.0.0.1:8000/classroom/notamember/myclass/?

Comment: Daniel's answer is a much better solution than this one. The url in urls.py may change at a later time. With this method you'll have to find all the places where it occurs and change accordingly, whereas if you use reverse() that will happen automatically.

Answer (score 65):

This should not be complicated. The argument to `HttpResponseRedirect` is simply a string, so the normal rules for building up a string apply here. However, I don't think you want the `theclass` variable in there, as that is a ClassRoom object, not a string. You presumably want the `classname` instead. adamk has given you the right answer here.

However, having said that you can just use a string, what you should actually do is use the `reverse` function. This is because you might later decide to change the URL structure, and rather than having to look through your code finding each place you've hard-coded the URL string, you should rely on having defined them in one single place: your urls.py file. So you should do something like this:

```
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse('notamember', kwargs={'classname': classname})
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: interesting ! i'll use the reverse function for urls from now on. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the shortcut `redirect` takes view names and model (which has `get_absolute_url` defined) names too.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect(leave_classroom)
```

Answer (score 0):

When everything seems not to be working i use return render and check if it is post request in case anybody refresh the page

```
if request.POST:
    message = "Thank you."
    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

The local() make the parameter accessible on the template

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting to the same URL, you can use the following to pass parameters.

```
 template_name = '/classroom/notamember.html'

return render(
                request,
                self.template_name,
                {'classname': 'classname', 'secondvariable': 'variable' }
            )
```