# Django redirect URL with parameter, inside urls.py file?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.9. Is there any way to redirect a URL with a parameter in my urls.py file?

I want to permanently redirect a URL like `/org/123/` to the corresponding URL `/neworg/123`.

I know [how to redirect within a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139973/django-return-httpresponseredirect-to-an-url-with-a-parameter), but I'm wondering if there's any way to do it solely inside `urls.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RedirectView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview). As long as the old and new url patterns have the same args and kwargs, you can use `pattern_name` to specify the url pattern to redirect to.

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^neworg/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', new_view, name='new_view'),
    url(r'^org/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='new_view'), name='old_view')
]
```

Comment: Weirdly I then start getting errors in other templates like `'<django.views.generic.base.RedirectView object at 0x10b2c00d0>' is not a callable or a dot-notation path` - it's definitely the redirect that is causing the problem, as if I comment it out then the error disappears too.

Comment: I had missed out `as_view`, the answer has been fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.